# RDD graph using ggplot with transition area extending lines to cut-off point

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data frame regarding labor force participation and age. At age 65 we have the pension eligibility age and we are interested in how labor supply reacts prior and after pension eligibility. Therefore, we as well plot a graph not taken into account the points around the pension eligibility age as it may cause some noise.

```
df<-data.frame( c(63, 63.5, 64, 64.5, 65, 65.5, 66, 66.5, 67), c(0.8, 0.7, 0.65, 0.5 , 0.5, 0.5, 0.15, 0.1 ,0))

colnames(df)<-c("age", "labor_force_participation")

df$pensionbreak<-cut(df$age,
                     breaks = c(-Inf, 64.4,65.5,Inf),
                     labels = c("prior pension", "transition area", "after pension"))

#Plot the graph without taking into account the transition area
p  + 
  geom_smooth(
    data = subset(df, pensionbreak != "transition area"),
    method = "lm", se = TRUE
  ) +
  xlab("age") + 
  ylab("fraction of males working") + 
  labs(color = "Retirement") + 
  theme_bw()
```

When plotting this graph, I do not take into account the transition area, but now I would like to extend the lines of the plot to the cut off point (i.e age of 65). More precisely, I would like to have my lines as in the figure below. Does anyone know how I can do this in R. I appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows - not very elegant but it works :)

```
require(tidyverse)
require(modelr)

# This is your subsetting
df_train <- df %>% filter(pensionbreak != "transition area")
df_predict <- tibble(age = 65, labor_force_participation = 0.5)

my_predictor <- function(x, pred, formula) {
  mod <- lm(formula, data = x)
  # This returns two types
  # type 1 is the predicted data
  # type 2 is the original data 
  bind_rows(pred, x) %>% 
    add_predictions(mod, var = "labor_force_participation") %>% 
    bind_rows(x, .id = "type")
}

# This applies the above function on your data - seperated by 
# the pensionbreak groups of data
dat <- df_train %>% 
  nest(data = c(age, labor_force_participation)) %>% 
  mutate(data_pred = map(data, my_predictor, df_predict, labor_force_participation ~ age)) %>% 
  unnest(data_pred) 

ggplot() +
  # Using type == 1 (predictions) for the line
  geom_line(data = dat %>% filter(type == 1),
            aes(x = age, y = labor_force_participation, col = pensionbreak),
            linetype = "dashed") +
  # Using type == 2 (original data) for the confidence area
  geom_smooth(data = dat %>% filter(type == 2),
              aes(x = age, y = labor_force_participation, col = pensionbreak),
              method = "lm") +
  xlab("age") + 
  ylab("fraction of males working") + 
  labs(color = "Retirement") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have, however, one additional question. How would you reformat your code if you want te create a graph in which we have two cut-off points. More precisely, let's say I want to visualize as well whether there is a jump at age 63.5. so that I have "dashed lines around this point and dashed around the age of 65. Do you have any idea how I could do that with this code? Thanks in advance.